# Dot(.) disambiguation is Flex/Bison

Tags: c, grammar, bison, yacc, lex

In my Flex lexer I define two different tokens containing a dot:

- float numbers: `{DIGIT}+\.{DIGIT}+` *(first)*
- the dot itself: `.`

Now, what do I need a single dot token? Because the language I'm writing my grammar for supports `.`-indexes, like: `someObject.someField` or `someObject.3` (where 3 is an array index).

The problem is when I'm testing it with a bidimensional array for example, like: `someArray.0.1`.

The grammar reads this as: `ID DOT FLOAT` while II would obviously want a `ID DOT(INTEGER DOT INTEGER)` reading.

What is the solution?

Here's the relevant part of the Bison grammar:

```
keypath                 :   ID DOT ID                                                           
                        |   ID DOT INTEGER                                                      
                        |   ID DOT inline_call                                                  
                        |   inline_call DOT ID                                                  
                        |   inline_call DOT INTEGER                                             
                        |   inline_call DOT inline_call                                         
                        |   keypath[previous] DOT ID                                            
                        |   keypath[previous] DOT INTEGER                                       
                        |   keypath[previous] DOT inline_call 
                        ;

number                  :   INTEGER                                                             
                        |   REAL                                                                
                        ;
```

Comment: You need to show the full grammar (or better yet : a minimal example that exhibits the same behavior). You haven't shown the `float` rule, or the `inline_call` rule, or any others that might be involved in this particular parse. The issue appears to be that you allow a `float` to be parsed where it shouldn't.

Comment: Issue, example s[2][3] in his grammar s.2.3 but 2.3 is the longest match in lex, It is giving the error s.floatindex is not there

Comment: Postpone the decision of recognizing floating point to parser

Comment: @VenkateshNandigama : good point. I missed that floats were already scanned as tokens by the lexer. There might still be issues in the grammar that allow floats to be parsed where they shouldn't, but you appear to have put your finger on the crux of the issue. Mind turning that into an answer ?

Comment: Thank you @Sander De Dycker, posted a sample answer. Please check it

Comment: Same as in your float rule. Escape it. Or quote it. Your .y file is irrelevant, only your .l file should have been posted here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postponing the decision of recognizing floats might help, I made simple example to understand

Parser specification:

```
 %{
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
  %}
  %token ID INT DOT
 %%
 Sd   : S'\n' { printf("accepted"); exit(0);}
      | R'\n' { printf("other purpose accepted"); exit(0);}
      ;
 S  : S DOT ID  {} 
    | S DOT INT {} 
    | ID        {}
    ;
 R  : INT DOT INT {printf("real number"); }
    ;
 %%

int main(){

yyparse();

return 0;

}
```

Lex specification:

```
 %{
   #include "d.tab.h"
 %}
 %%
 [0-9]+           {  return INT;}
 [a-zA-Z][A-Za-z0-9]* { return ID;}
 "."                { return DOT;}
 .|\n              { return *yytext;}
%%
```

Now it recognize s.2.3.